# I want to pass the environment name i.g UAT or QA or Production as argument while running my tests with maven. (i.e mvn test QA or mn test UAT)

Tags: java, maven, properties

I want to pass the environment name i.g UAT or QA or Production as argument while running my tests with maven. (i.e mvn test QA or mvn test UAT). I have properties file in my project for respective environments in my project.

So, if I run mvn test QA it should use all the properties which are there in qa.properties files while running the tests.

How should I achieve this?

Comment: You could use Maven profiles. Are you using Spring? How are you loading the mentioned properties in you code?

Comment: Does your code behave different in different environments?

Comment: No. code is same for all environments. I am working in selenium TestNG.

Answer (score 0):

create multiple properties files i.e. one for each environment. Example: application-qa.properties, application-uat.properties and add properties as per environment.
Now, open application.properties file and following properties:

**spring.profiles.active=qa**

Spring will pick up the qa property file from your workspace.